# Safer alternative to “opaque”?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, ambiguity

As a child I was taught that *opaque* means *doesn't let any light through at all*, as opposed to *translucent* (lets some light through, but diffused/frosted) or *transparent* (completely clear, lets you see clear images).

However, it seems a lot of people use *opaque* as synonymous with *translucent*. Indeed if you ask Google for its definition of *opaque*, and looks at its definition, usage example (“opaque with steam”), and synonyms, it seems to support the *translucent*-synonymous usage. I don't know what Google's data source is for their definitions, but it's clearly descriptive of real usage (as most dictionaries are), not prescriptive of how a word “ought” to be used.

I've certainly heard people (mis)use *opaque* as synonymous with *translucent* in everyday speech.

So now I'm looking for a single word to use in place of *opaque* to firmly communicate that the thing being described is completely impenetrable to light.

Comment: Even thesaurs.com obfuscates the distinction, http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/opaque?s=t, but it really is an artificial distinction according to the etymology http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=opaque&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: just use *opaque* (because it **is** the right word) but back it up somewhere else in the literature with *100% light-blocking* or something similar.

Comment: @ScotM - So how about "obfuscated"?

Comment: Observant, @HotLicks, but I prefer *totally opaque* :-) or better yet *absolutely* opaque. The physics exchange may have a technical term.

Comment: It turns out the *impenetrable by light* distinction is the consequence of a specialized technical definition in physics. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145333/why-is-an-opaque-body-opaque It is probably safe to assume that the more educated an audience is, the more likely they are to understand the distinction intuitively.

Comment: How about "attenuates transmission of electromagnetic radiation in the visible light range by a factor of 100 dB or greater".

Comment: Given the existing confusion between opaque and translucent, it's unlikely than any *single word* will be understood more accurately. I'm afraid you'll have to swallow your inner pedant and use *"totally opaque"*, or some such modifier.

Comment: I blame programs like Photoshop using words like "opacity" instead of "translucence".

Comment: "Alpha 1". Of course, this will only make sense to computer graphics folks, who (should) know the proper meaning of *opaque* anyway.

Comment: @fredsbend But then you would have to invert the scale so that "100% translucent" would mean fully transparent. This may go against people's intuition.

Comment: @nitro2k01 I don't see why. "100% translucence" means transparent. What else might one think?

Comment: @fredsbend My point is that it probably makes more intuitive sense to control how "visible" the layer is over how "invisible" it is. Therefore, Adobe elected to let you control the opacity rather than the translucence. What I mean by inverting the scale, is that if you were controlling translucence rather than opacity, you would either have to place the control slider to the left to turn the layer ON, or accept that 100% translucence is on the left side of the slider element.

Comment: If Photoshop wanted to describe controlling visibility or invisibility of an underlying object, they could have used those words. If people have a hard time with degrees of invisibility, Photoshop could have called it "hidden" or "hiding factor". But by taking "opaque", which was previously not considered to come in degrees, and turning it into "opacity", which ranges down to zero, has, as the questioner suggested, destroyed the original sense of the word.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In writing we sometimes have to be redundant.  In case you are misunderstood, I suggest you use **"totally opaque"** or **"one-hundred percent opaque".**

Comment: I think that the problem is just the 'supposedly misunderstood' meaning of opaque!!

Comment: "Totally opaque" is probably the most direct way to avoid the OP's anxiety.

Comment: "Absolutely" or "completely opaque"

Comment: "fully opaque" is also used a lot

Comment: I'd suggest that, if you call it "totally opaque", you also address how that "totally" is totally redundant.

Answer (score 6):

I think that with [non-transparent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/non-transparent) you are on the safe side:

> - Not able to be seen through; opaque:
>     a work rendered in non-transparent acrylic. (ODO)

- also *non-translucent*.

Comment: I don't know -- "non-transparent" would be more likely to be confused with "translucent" than "opaque" would.

Comment: How can you confuse NON-transparent with translucent?

Comment: If you told someone you had two pieces of glass, one "non-transparent" and one "opaque", I'm guessing that most would pick the second as obscuring things better.

Comment: I may agree with you...but OP question is about his assumption that people tend to confuse 'opaque' with 'translucent'. To convey the idea of opaque I think non-transparent is a good and clear option.

Comment: "Totally opaque" is probably the better choice, to answer OP's worries.

Comment: Sorry, but it is like saying 'totally translucent'. OP is looking for an alternative word to opaque!!

Comment: @Josh The ambiguity is that some people use ‘opaque’ to mean ‘preventing light from getting through (but not necessarily 100% of it)’. Something like ‘completely opaque’ cannot possibly make any sense unless you interpret the _completely_ as reinforcing the blocking of the light, making it unambiguously mean ‘preventing any light whatsoever from getting through’. ‘Totally translucent’ makes absolutely no sense to me, like saying something is ‘completely semi-transparent’, whereas ‘completely opaque’ is perfectly understandable and unambiguous.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I agree with you...but if we are to answer OP question we have to consider his assumptions, that is, 'a lot of people use opaque a synonymous of translucent'. So it is not a question of percentage...a different,  alternative and unambiguous word is requested!!! Opaque:Impenetrable by light; neither transparent nor translucent.

Comment: Something *translucent* is neither opaque or transparent. Which means that *non-translucent* is one of these two. The ambiguity still exists.

Comment: Referring to an opaque object as "non-transparent" is like referring to forks as "non-spoons"; not inaccurate, but also not useful.

Comment: @bcrist it is accurate and useful in the quoted example - you can buy ink-based acrylic paint, which shows the colour behind it through so is called 'transparent acrylic', and you can buy opaque medium to mix with it so the colour doesn't show through, and the resulting mixture is referred to as 'non-transparent acrylic' as it is ink based but does not allow the underlying colour to be seen through it, whereas 'opaque acrylic' is manufactured using opaque pigments rather than inks so is inherently opaque. But it's usefulness is rather niche.

Answer (score 3):

Consider ***lightproof***. Sounds *foolproof*.

> Impenetrable by light [[TFD]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lightproof)

That said, you can make something lightproof by using an opaque material also. Another similar term is *light-tight*.

Answer (score 2):

Like others I have heard the word used variously and sometimes with apparent contradiction. So I am quoting below the range of meanings given by the OED. Multifarious references are given against each, which I have not repeated. There are also a host of 'special references' which I have not included. This may not answer your question by providing you with an alternative word. But it will perhaps confirm that none of the meanings imply complete impenetrability to light. To achieve that I would suggest you use that term ***impenetrable to light***.

> A. adj.
>    1.    a. Lying in shadow; dark, dim, not illuminated. Also fig. Now rare.  b. Of an object or surface: not reflecting or emitting light;
>   not shining or lustrous.
>
> 2. a. Not transmitting light, not transparent or translucent; impenetrable to sight. Also fig.    b. Not transmitting a form of
>      radiation other than light, as sound, heat, or X-rays. Freq. with to.
> 3. a. Hard to understand; obscure in meaning; not clear or lucid. †b. Impervious to reason; stupid, obtuse. Obs.
>
>    4. Linguistics. Categories »    a. Not obvious in meaning; esp. (of a word) that was originally a compound or derivative but is now a
>         simplex, and so has a meaning that cannot be deduced from its form or
>         sound.  b. Of a rule in phonology: that cannot be extrapolated from
>         every occurrence; subject to exceptions, esp. as a result of language
>         change. C–D. 1974   S. R. Anderson Organization of Phonol. xii. 209
>         Historical change can be seen to operate on nontransparent (or opaque)
>         rules so as to make them more transparent or to eliminate them from
>         the grammar. 1997   W. J. Idsardi in I. Roca Derivations & Constraints
>         in Phonol. 373   Hebrew spirantization is a typical example of an
>         opaque rule, because later rules, such as vowel deletion, obscure the
>         application environment in the surface form.
>
> †a. Chiefly poet. A region of complete darkness; a place where light
>   cannot penetrate. Also fig. Obs.
>        b. A shade for the eyes. rare.
>        c. A garment or material that is opaque rather than translucent.    d. A colour or finish that completely hides the previous finish. Also:
>   one that is matt, not shiny or lustrous.
>        e. Min. A mineral that appears black in thin section when viewed in polarized light.
>    2. Photogr.    a. A substance used for producing an opaque area on a negative, as in retouching. Now hist.    b. A photographic print made
>   on opaque paper, as opposed to a transparency. Now hist. 1959
>   Recomm. for Density & Contrast Range of Monochrome Films (B.S.I.) 5
>   Prints of black-and-white photographic opaques should be made in such
>   a way that a middle tone..will have a reflection density within the
>   range 0·5 to 0·7.

Comment: Ah, but by "light" do you mean visible light, ultraviolet, infrared, or anything in the electromagnetic spectrum?

Comment: *Penetrable,* I think. Also: this would be easier to follow if the formatting was better. Markdown handles numbered lists and a linebreak can be forced by ending a line with two spaces.

Comment: @WS2 I don't see how you can say "none of the meanings imply complete impenatrability [sic] to light" when definition 2 agrees with me: "2. a. Not transmitting light, not transparent or translucent; impenetrable to sight. Also fig. b. Not transmitting a form of radiation other than light, as sound, heat, or X-rays. Freq. with to.". Note they're using "transmit" as "allow to pass through", in contrast to how they use "emitting" in 1. b.

Comment: @Spiff Is 'impentrable to sight', the same thing as 'impenetrable to light'? I see nothing which implies the latter.

Comment: @WS2 When "impenetrable to sight" is offered as further explanation of "Not transmitting light, not transparent or translucent" in the same definition, it's certainly the same thing as "impenetrable to light". Unless perhaps if one were to believe that sight is a mysterious sensory experience that doesn't involve light. :-)

Comment: @Spiff Doesn't that rather depend on how you are defining 'sight'? I mean it might be possible to see light through a frosted glass window but for it to be impossible to determine what was on the other side, other than some vague forms. Wouldn't that be impenetrability to sight?

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Thank you for correcting the typo. May the bird of paradise attend you.

Comment: @WS2 No, it does not depend on how one defines 'sight'.  Spiff is right here.  The "impenetrable to sight" is merely explanatory of what "Not transmitting light" results in.  Opaque does indeed mean "no transmission of light of any kind at all" but far too many Americans are ignorant of their own language these days.  The real problem comes from complete idiots misusing the language, because they are lazy and uneducated (in the sense of "not bothering to take advantage of the education they were provided").  It might be a losing cause, however.  Language changes all the time.

Comment: Yes, I'm being rabidly pedantic here.  And yes, I'm an American.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Scientifically speaking:

Transparency refers to the ability of a material to allow light to pass through *without being **scattered** at all*; it is simply blocked in various degrees.  This enables materials to be semi-transparent.  Opacity is the opposite of transparency, the ability to block light attempting to pass through.

Translucency, on the other hand, refers exclusively to the ability of light to pass through and is not concerned whether the light is scattered (refraction).  It is a superset of transparency/opacity.  All transparent objects are also translucent, but the reverse is not always true.

If you want to be *correct*, you may use opaque as described.  You may also use **non-translucent**, as it indicates a complete inability for light to pass through.  If you want to be *understood*, I recommend using **inpermeable** or **inpenetrable**.  Note that these can also refer to fluids, gases, or other forces attempting to pass through.

Answer (score 0):

I grew up with the understanding of opaque the same way you did.  In the world of the web, though, meanings of some well-understood words have been hi-jacked.
There is an attribute for images in CSS (Cascading Style Sheet) called 'opacity', which refers to a sliding scale of 'opaqueness', if you will.  So setting opacity to 100% makes the image 'totally opaque', and 0% would be totally transparent, and anything in between could be referred to as some level of translucence.

Maybe opaque has always had implicit gradations, but with this new understanding approaching ubiquity, it probably is safer to qualify opaque, as Centaurus suggests.

Comment: Of course, if, as you say, something can be "totally transparent" (implying that it might otherwise have been less transparent than that) then "transparent" suffers the same problem as "opaque".

Comment: If I have a "blackness" scale indicating varying shades of grey - with black at one end and white at the other - does that mean that "black" somehow now means "grey" - no.  "Opacity" or opaqueness is the same - it's a scale from opaque to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

**Blocking** sounds pretty straightforward. As opposed to transparency and opaqueness, which may have variable levels, the **light blocking** materials either block light or don't. Rarely you will see a person confused about the meaning of this word.

Answer (score 0):

Simple examples...

**Opaque:**        Wood, metal or any solid object, etc.

**Translucent:**   Butter Paper, etc.

**Transparent:**   Glass sheet, windows, etc.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, though. The original poster understands what these terms mean; what is sought is an alternative to *opaque* because it is sometimes used to mean *translucent*.

Answer (score -3):

As for your usage for "completely impenetrable to light",

1. Dark (n)
2. Darkened (adj)
3. Obscure

seem to be more appropriate.

Comment: Something *dark* is not necessarily "impenetrable to light".  A dark sky, for example, may still feature starlight or moonlight.  The questioner is looking for an alternative to opaque that will not be misread as translucent. "The material is opaque" means no light is seen through it, not that it is dark. A disk of unpainted steel is opaque (you can't see through it unless you've got Xray vision), but it is most certainly not *dark*.